# Load dtypes into Python via a separate mapping table that can be linked to the primary dataframe to specify the dtypes by column

Tags: python, pandas

Although new to python, i seem to be getting the hang of it.

However, i will be dealing with massive databases with hundreds of columns and specifying dtypes for each seem to be a very code intensive excersize i.e. having to specifically write out column names and convert to a certain dtype.

Question: Is it possible to create an excel/CSV file with all the columns from the primary database down a column and have a separate column for dtypes for each. Then linking this to the primary dataframe to specify the dtype based on the secondary dataframe? i.e. primary database has 100 columns and i load a separate table with those 100 columns down the rows and just have 100 rows + a column with dtypes (str, int, etc.) that can be indexed off of to specify the exact dtype for each row in the primary database?

this is similar to how you would do it in excel i.e. index matching off of a separate mapping table

Comment: Why do you need to specify the dtypes? Generally, pandas does a good job of inferring dtypes, especially if you are importing from a database. What, *exactly* are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have another dataframe with correct dtypes or you can create a dictionary of {columnname: dtype} then you can use it to change dtypes like below

```py
d = {
    "A": np.random.choice("A B C".split(), 5),
    "B": np.random.rand(5),
    "C": np.arange(5)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df2 = df.astype("O")
print(df2.dtypes)

## convert using dtypes of another dataframe
print(df2.astype(df.dtypes).dtypes)

## convert using dictionary
print(df2.astype({"B":"f", "C":"i"}).dtypes)
```